# Is there any way to use PictureBox.ImageLocation in a for loop?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I've been trying to create some basic C++ programs using GUI and VS, but it's always been a lot of work with Picture boxes. If, for example, i was trying to make a BlackJack game, I would have to do something like:

```
if(x==1)
   PictureBox1.ImageLocation="//The ace card"
if(x==2)
   PictureBox1.ImageLocation="//The card with two on it"
 .
 .
 .
if(x==52)
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation="//The last card in the deck"
```

Where x is a random number generated from 1 to 52, and is the card the player hits. Also, I would have to repeat this for at least 4-5 Picture Boxes. Is there any way I could put all this in a for loop and be done with it? Or is there any way to make this more efficient? I literally needed 2500 lines of code for a simple blackjack game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be made for efficient. For instance, by using arrays.  Just note that creating arrays of managed types is different in C++/CLI than in standard C++. See [How to: Use Arrays in C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-use-arrays-in-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160).

Create an array of 52 strings for the card locations, and then use `x` to index into that array, eg:

```cpp
using namespace System;

array< String^ >^ cards = {
    "//The ace card",
    "//The card with two on it",
    ...
    "//The last card in the deck"
};

...

PictureBox1.ImageLocation = cards[x-1];
```

You can do the same thing with the `PictureBox`s, too.  Create an array of 5 `PictureBox`s, then your `for` loop can index through that array, eg:

```cpp
using namespace System;

array< PictureBox^ >^ pb = {
    PictureBox1,
    PictureBox2,
    ...
    PictureBox5
};

...

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    // use pb[i] as needed...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "array of handles is not allowed E1959" when declaring the array of strings.